# Parsing value from onCreate method to public class

Tags: java, android, json

I have declared strings st1,st2,st3..st7 in a public class. I'm getting value from MySQL database using JSON in protected onCreate method. Now I want to pass it to the strings st1,st2,st3..st7, so that I can pass it to the string seat which is declared in the public class. So, that I can use it below in onCreate method for further use.

```
public class SeatBookingTwo extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
ViewGroup layout;

private Context mContext;
private Activity mActivity;

private String mJSONURLString = "http://paolosfa......";

String st1 ="", st2="" , st3=""   ,st4=""  ,st5="" , st6=""  ,st7="" ;

String seats = st1 + "" + st2 + "" + st3 +"" + '/' + "" + st4 + "" + st5 + "" + st6 + "" + st7;

List<TextView> seatViewList = new ArrayList<>();

int seatSize = 100;
int seatGaping = 10;

int STATUS_AVAILABLE = 1;
int STATUS_BOOKED = 2;
int STATUS_RESERVED = 3;
String selectedIds = "";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_seat_booking_two);

    layout = findViewById(R.id.layoutSeat);
    seats = "/" + seats;

    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    mActivity = SeatBookingTwo.this;

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);

    // Initialize a new JsonArrayRequest instance
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.POST,
            mJSONURLString,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray seat) {
                    // Do something with response
                    //mTextView.setText(response.toString());

                    // Process the JSON
                    try{
                        // Loop through the array elements
                        for(int i=0;i<seat.length();i++){
                            // Get current json object
                            JSONObject student = seat.getJSONObject(i);

                            // Get the current student (json object) data
                             st1 = student.getString("st1");
                             st2 = student.getString("st2");
                             st3 = student.getString("st3");
                             st4 = student.getString("st4");

                             st5 = student.getString("st5");
                             st6 = student.getString("st6");
                             st7 = student.getString("st7");

                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener(){
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){

                }
            }
    );

    // Add JsonArrayRequest to the RequestQueue
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);

    LinearLayout layoutSeat = new LinearLayout(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    layoutSeat.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layoutSeat.setLayoutParams(params);
    layoutSeat.setPadding(8 * seatGaping, 8 * seatGaping, 8 * seatGaping, 8 * seatGaping);
    layout.addView(layoutSeat);

    LinearLayout layout = null;

    int count = 0;

    for (int index = 0; index < seats.length(); index++) {
        if (seats.charAt(index) == '/') {
            layout = new LinearLayout(this);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            layoutSeat.addView(layout);
        } else if (seats.charAt(index) == '1') {
            count++;
            TextView view = new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(seatSize, seatSize);
            layoutParams.setMargins(seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping);
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 2 * seatGaping);
            view.setId(count);
            view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_seats_booked);
            view.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            view.setTag(STATUS_BOOKED);
            view.setText(count + "");
            view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 9);
            layout.addView(view);
            seatViewList.add(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else if (seats.charAt(index) == '2') {
            count++;
            TextView view = new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(seatSize, seatSize);
            layoutParams.setMargins(seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping);
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 2 * seatGaping);
            view.setId(count);
            view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_seats_book);
            view.setText(count + "");
            view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 9);
            view.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            view.setTag(STATUS_AVAILABLE);
            layout.addView(view);
            seatViewList.add(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else if (seats.charAt(index) == '3') {
            count++;
            TextView view = new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(seatSize, seatSize);
            layoutParams.setMargins(seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping);
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 2 * seatGaping);
            view.setId(count);
            view.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_seats_reserved);
            view.setText(count + "");
            view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 9);
            view.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            view.setTag(STATUS_RESERVED);
            layout.addView(view);
            seatViewList.add(view);
            view.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else if (seats.charAt(index) == '_') {
            TextView view = new TextView(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(seatSize, seatSize);
            layoutParams.setMargins(seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping, seatGaping);
            view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
            view.setText("");
            layout.addView(view);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if ((int) view.getTag() == STATUS_AVAILABLE) {
        if (selectedIds.contains(view.getId() + ",")) {
            selectedIds = selectedIds.replace(+view.getId() + ",", "");
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_seats_book);
        } else {
            selectedIds = selectedIds + view.getId() + ",";
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_seats_selected);
        }
    } else if ((int) view.getTag() == STATUS_BOOKED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Seat " + view.getId() + " is Booked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else if ((int) view.getTag() == STATUS_RESERVED) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Seat " + view.getId() + " is Reserved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion would be instead of creating `String seats = st1 + "" + st2 + "" + st3 +"" + '/' + "" + st4 + "" + st5 + "" + st6 + "" + st7;` simply declare

```
String seats = "";
```

then in onResponse do`seats = st1 + "" + st2 + "" + st3 +"" + '/' + "" + st4 + "" + st5 + "" + st6 + "" + st7;`

I would have done the above and used anywhere required and also remember strings are ummutable

Comment: Are u able to check whether you are getting values in st1...st7 in first place ??

Comment: first place means? i m getting the value from database to the st1,st2,...st7 which is in onresponce method ...